# Downgrade embedded tomcat version in maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

My Springboot application was build in tomcat 9.0 with java version of 1.8 and our server has tomcat 6 with java version of 1.7. I have already downgrade our java version in facet.

How can i downgrade the embedded tomcat in maven? Do I need to generate a new initialize from springIO?

Comment: Are you publishing this as a War onto an existing Tomcat servlet? If not, explain how an embedded server has anything to do with "_our server has tomcat 6 with java version 1.7_"

Comment: @RandyCasburn My springboot application was build in tomcat 9.0 and you're correct were deploying a war file in a server with Tomcat version of 6. But I've read in Springboot documentary that Tomcat version should be 8.5 or later. Maybe either we need to convert our system from springboot to struts or we update our server tomcat version.

Comment: That is much clearer, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the SpringBoot docs:

> Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE requires Java 8 and is compatible up to Java
>   11 (included). Spring Framework 5.1.3.RELEASE or above is also
>   required.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements

So if you must stay on 1.7 and Tomcat 6, you'll need to move away from SpringBoot and back to your older solutions.

Comment: which one is better? because when we update our server tomcat version maybe other application running in our server will be affected and to convert our system from springboot to spring.
Thank you.

Comment: SpringBoot makes things SO much easier. How? Removing a ton of boilerplate code that we write and rewrite and rewrite and then have to test. This is done through the magic of IOC and Dependency injection that moves most of the boilerplate to the framework. That means we write less and test less to achieve the same goals. But, as you recognize, any system migration is difficult. If you are considering moving in that direction (updating), then you should also consider Spring Webflux as an alternative to SpringMVC.